# Criar uma tarefa agendada no Windows XP 32-bits

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, linha-de-comando, 32-bits

Eu quero criar ou modificar uma tarefa por linha de comando, isso na mesma máquina.
Eu estou usando o comando `Schtasks` com argumento `/Create`.

Mas consegui somente no **Windows 8**, quando levei o **BAT** para a máquina **Windows XP (32-Bits)** não funcionou.

```
schtasks /Create /TN "MyTask" /TR C:\MyTask.bat /SC Daily /ST 07:00:00
```

Retorna a mensagem:

```
ERRO: Sintaxe inválida
```

Mas não especifica qual.

Não achei maneira de fazer com VBS, pesquisei em vários tópicos de outros países, mas nada, acredito que seja a versão do Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente não é possível criar (e recriar) tarefas por linha de comando no Windows XP.

A solução que arrumei foi criar em uma única tarefa vários disparadores o que é bem chato, por isso preferia que um BAT o fizesse.

Eu ativei o `checkbox` opção **Mostrar vários agendamentos**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim pude ter acesso para o botão 'Novo' onde inclui um disparador com repetidor idêntico ao anterior, mas com uma hora a mais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando criei um pra cada horário (padrão 24 horas), sendo de 00:00 até 23:00

Então quando o sistema inicia (valendo lembrar que todos os disparadores iniciam sem autenticação do usuário, ou seja somente após o LOGON).

Pra completar eu copiei o arquivo `*.JOB` da pasta TASKS para a pasta da minha aplicação.

```
copy %windir%\tasks\mystask.job %homedrive%\myapp\
```

Como até pra parar ('/end') ou deletar ('/delete') ficam dando erros eu criei no menu da minha aplicação um método pra "LIGAR" e "DESLIGAR" o agendamento.

```
@ECHO OFF
:STARTAPP
IF EXIST %windir%\tasks\mystask.job (
SET ABKP=ON
) ELSE (
SET ABKP=OFF
)
CLS
ECHO [1] Menu 1
ECHO [2] Menu 2
ECHO [3] Ativar ou desativar AUTOBACKUP: %ABKP%
ECHO [4] Menu 4
ECHO.
SET /P SLT= Selecione um dos itens acima: 
IF "%SLT%"=="1" (GOTO OPTION1)
IF "%SLT%"=="2" (GOTO OPTION2)
IF "%SLT%"=="3" (GOTO OPTION3)
IF "%SLT%"=="4" (GOTO OPTION2)

:OPTION3
IF EXIST %windir%\tasks\mystask.job (
COPY %HOMEDRIVE%\myapp\mytask.job %windir%\tasks\
) ELSE (
DEL %windir%\tasks\mystask.job
)
GOTO STARTAPP
```

E o melhor, como funciona somente após o usuário "logado" então independente da máquina que eu colocar ou usuário que estiver rodando quando o arquivo `*.JOB` é copiado para pasta **TASKS** e você verifica as propriedades ele muda automaticamente o usuário pra o que estiver rodando, garantindo que vai funcionar já que não pede autenticação.